# UIAlertView not responding to button event

Tags: ios, uialertview

First time working with `UIAlertViews` and I can't figure out why this doesn't work. When I click on either button, the alert closes, but there is no **NSLog** output. What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out. Thanks!

.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)resetPassword:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Reset"
                                                      message:@"A temporary password will be sent to you at the address we have on file."
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
    [alert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) NSLog(@"button 0");
    if (buttonIndex == 1) NSLog(@"button 1");
}
```

Comment: Delegate is key here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you never set the delegate on the UIAlertView. It should be:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Reset"
                                                  message:@"A temporary password will be sent to you at the address we have on file."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
```

This way the UIAlertView is able to call your method, `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`, when the user taps a button.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that myself. I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `delegate` to nil. You need to set it to your controller instance, like this:

```
- (IBAction)resetPassword:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Reset"
                  message:@"A temporary password will be sent to you at the address we have on file."
                  delegate:self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                  otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Implementing the `-alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method does little good if you never give the UIAlertView an object to serve as the delegate.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that myself.